# R: is there a way to speed up sorting of strings?

Tags: r, sorting

I was trying to sort a vector of strings, see MWE below

```
# example R code    
N=1e8; K=100
set.seed(1)
id3 = sample(sprintf("i%07d",1:(N/K)), N, TRUE)
pt = proc.time()
sort(id3)
data.table::timetaken(pt)
```

and it didn't complete on my computer for almost 5 minutes, so I cancelled it.

I note that in Julia the same can be performed in about 90 seconds on my laptop

```
# example Julia cde
const M=100_000_000; const K=100
srand(1)
svec1 = rand(["i"*dec(k,7) for k in 1:M÷K], M)
@time sort(svec1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `method = "radix"` to use radix sort to speed up the sorting

```
N=1e8; K=100
set.seed(1)
id3 = sample(sprintf("i%07d",1:(N/K)), N, TRUE)
pt = proc.time()
sort(id3, method="radix")
data.table::timetaken(pt)
```

it completed in 18 seconds on my laptop.